# change attribute value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

i am trying to change an attribute at the img tag and it's not working i do not know why. My code is changeing the BIG img source and the ZOOM source, but the code only changes the source but not the ZOOM, here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <script src='jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
    <script src='jquery.elevatezoom.js'></script>
    <!--script src='jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script-->
    <script>
    function colorImage(x){
    var newsrc = x.src.replace("thumb", "large");
    var d = document.getElementById("zoom_06_l"); 
    d.src = newsrc;
    d.setAttribute("data-zoom-image", newsrc);
}
    </script>

</head>

<style>
a{
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.element{
width:150px;
}

.element .code {
text-align:center;
padding:10px;
}
</style>

<body>
<div style="width:960px;margin:0 auto;">
                <img id="zoom_06_l" src="large/001.jpg" width="960" data-zoom-image="large/001.jpg"/>


                <div id="gallery">
                    <a href="#" data-image="large/001.jpg" data-zoom-image="large/001.jpg"> 
                        <div class="element" style="float:left;margin-right:5px;">
                            <img id="zoom_06" src="thumb/001.png" /><br> 
                            <div class="code">דגם מספר : 0025</div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" data-image="large/30001.png" data-zoom-image="large/30001.png"> 
                        <div class="element" style="float:left;margin-right:5px;">
                            <img onclick="javascript:colorImage(this)" id="zoom_06" src="thumb/30001.png" /><br> 
                            <div class="code">דגם מספר : 30001</div>
                        </div>          
                    </a>

                </div>


</div>




<script>
    $("#zoom_06_l").elevateZoom({
    zoomType    : "lens",
    lensShape : "round",
    lensSize : 250 
    }); 
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

data-zoom-image at the img with id zoom_06_l is not changing i do not know why.
any help ?

Comment: hi,thanks for answering, plain javascript

Answer (score 0):

In place of

```
d.setAttribute("data-zoom-image", newsrc);
```

try using this

```
d.dataset.zoomImage = newsrc;
```

For details please refer to

"https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes"

Comment: Well there was neither a problem with your code too, I just wanted to try another option. Can you share a plunker for me to see?

Comment: why to u mean "plunker"?

Comment: plunker is an online editor. It is easier to check. Well, I have tried running your html with me and it seems to work fine. Both src and data-zoom-image attributes are getting updated.

Comment: but see the color of the door in the zoom..it is white and not brown

Comment: sorry..i mean the zoom yes working..but try different images...will show only 1 zoom image for all images

Comment: I am really trying hard to understand your problem, however, unfortunately not able to do so. Can you please ellaborate

Comment: In the meantime, I noticed that you have given "zoom_06" id to html elements. May be that is causing problem.